# Codeception and GitLab CI can't get it running

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, codeception

Currently I am trying to configure Codeception in GitLab CI, but getting problems over problems.

Here is my gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
  - run


variables:
  TEST_URL: "example"


run-chrome:
  stage: run
  tags:
    - docker
  image: php:7.2-cli-alpine
  services:
    - name: selenium/standalone-chrome
      alias: chrome
  script:
    - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
    - composer install
    - echo Running tests on $TEST_URL
    - vendor/bin/codecept run --env docker-chrome
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - tests/_output
    expire_in: 7 day
    when: on_failure
```

I am using Codeception 4.0 in my composer.json.

My acceptance.suite.yml looks like:

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
  enabled:
    - Helper\WebDriver
    - Helper\Acceptance

extensions:
  enable:
    - Codeception\Extension\Recorder

step_decorators:
  - \Codeception\Step\Retry
  - \Codeception\Step\TryTo

env:       
  docker-chrome:
    modules:
      config:
        Helper\WebDriver:
          browser: chrome
          host: chrome
          wait: 5
          capabilities:
            chromeOptions:
              args: ["--headless", "--disable-gpu"]
```

The Error message I am getting is:

> [RuntimeException] Call to undefined method AcceptanceTester::seeInCurrentURL

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Does Helper\Webdriver extend WebDriver module?

Comment: I solved it. Had to add the modules to the composer.json, since codeception 4 requires the modules to be loaded separately.

Comment: @Tastiko this could solve my problem can you post what modules you added?